# DomCrawler FilterXPath Query

Tags: php, symfony, xpath, domcrawler

I'm have some html such as below:

```
<html>
<body> 
... other html stuff ...
<form method="post" action="goSomewhere">
    <input type="hidden" value="something">
    <input type="hidden" value="something2">
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="123">Stuff 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked name="456">Stuff 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="789">Stuff 3</td></tr>
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm trying to select everything in the `<form>` except for the tag with a particular name (innerhtml, that is). Here's the query I'm using:

```
$query = "//form//td[not(normalize-space() = 'Stuff 2')]";
```

This successfully filters *out* that particular `<td>` of content, but the problem is that it *then* only returns `<td>` content. As you can see, there are other `<input>` that are not in the `<table>` and I need those too.

Can anyone help with this query please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `//form//td[not(normalize-space() = 'Stuff 2')]/input|//input[not(ancestor::table)]`.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work! Do you have an idea how I can just get all the items in the `form` tag? For some reasons the `input` return seems to be empty. I actually still need the `table/td` content as well. I tried changing `../form|//form[not(ancestor::form)]` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you explain which nodes you miss?

Comment: If I do a `print_r` of the crawler object (containing all the inputs) it prints empty objects. So basically I'm altering my original request: instead of getting all the inputs (minus that particular one with "Stuff 2" name), I'd like to get all the content between `<form>` and `</form>`.

Comment: You could use the `reduce()` method of the `Crawler` class which takes a callback that is used to filter nodes.